# React Hook Form problem with validating using validate function

Tags: reactjs, typescript, validation, react-hook-form

Hey I'm currently working on validation using customized Antd inputs and React Hook Form.

Currently I have problem with validating fields for URLs (single url and image one) with regex.

I've checked both of regex and they are working

Generally I can't submit the form with correct data, the problem happens within the validation using regex

The form part

```js
<Controller
        as={
          <InputField
            label="URL"
            name="url"
            placeholder="Enter URL"
            error={errors.url}
            errorText="URL Error"
          />
        }
        control={control}
        type="text"
        name="url"
        defaultValue=""
        rules={{
          validate: (value) => {
            return INPUT.urlPattern.test(value);
          }
        }}
      />
      <Controller
        as={
          <InputField
            label="Image Url"
            name="imageUrl"
            placeholder="enter ImageURL"
            error={errors.imageUrl}
            errorText="Error on imageUrl"
          />
        }
        control={control}
        type="text"
        name="imageUrl"
        defaultValue=""
        rules={{
          validate: (value) => {
            return INPUT.imageURLPattern.test(value);
          }
        }}
      />
```

Custom antd input component render function

```js
return (
    <>
      <label className="label" htmlFor={name}>
        {label}
      </label>
      <Styled.Input
        placeholder={placeholder}
        maxLength={maxLength}
        value={value}
        onChange={handleInputCounter}
        {...(counter
          ? {
              suffix: (
                <Styled.WordCounter>
                  {counterValue} / {maxLength}
                </Styled.WordCounter>
              )
            }
          : {})}
      />
      {error && <p className="error">{errorText}</p>}
    </>
  );
```

I've prepared little demo on codesandbox

https://codesandbox.io/s/react-hook-form-validate-antd-gyhnh?file=/src/EntryForm.tsx